# Chrome Canary - When Developers Tools Are Open Hover States Do Not Appear

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Not sure if this is a bug or if I have some how created an issue with my settings but I have noticed recently that when I am using Chrome Canary [Version 27.0.1423.0 canary] and I open the Developer Tools, I can no longer activate hover states on any websites. If I close the developer tools, I can active the hover states again.

I have tested this on the latest version of Chrome [Version 25.0.1364.97 m] and when I open the Developer Tools I can still activate hover states.

I did some research and didn't find any one reporting a similar issue so I figured I would ask here. Is this a bug or a configuration issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177612. Please check you don't have the `Settings` - `Overrides` - `Emulate touch events` checkbox toggled on. It recently started inhibiting the mousemove/mouseover/mouseout events, so that the page behavior would more closely resemble that on a touch-enabled (== pointer-less) device.

Comment: grrrr that setting. I spent half day figuring out what went wrong

Comment: As of the current Canary, your mouse pointer will look in a way that will prevent you from forgetting that. Ever! :)